# Parsing an API response with GSON and Retrofit, values remain null

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

**My App class:**

```
class App(

var id: Int,
var name: String,
var description: String,
var url: String,
var packageName: String,
var appVersion: String,
var iconMediaUUID: String?,
var created: String,
var createdBy: String

) : Serializable
```

**E D I T:** I also tried the `@SerializedName` annotation, no success.

**My Retrofit API call:**

```
  @GET("/api/app-list")
  suspend fun getApplications(): Response<List<App>>
```

**The JSON returned from the API:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "facebook",
        "description": "face book",
        "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana",
        "packageName": "com.facebook.katana",
        "appVersion": "1",
        "iconMediaUUID": null,
        "created": "2023-09-05 09:20",
        "createdBy": "ava@mail.hu"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "twitter",
        "description": "X",
        "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android",
        "packageName": "com.twitter.android",
        "appVersion": "43",
        "iconMediaUUID": "e2913bc1-4963-4a3e-85bf-8244b5b42979",
        "created": "2023-09-05 10:11",
        "createdBy": "ava@mail.hu"
    }
]
```

**My Retrofit instance:**

```
private fun getBackendClient(): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(BACKEND_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    fun callBackend(): Endpoints {
        return getBackendClient().create(Endpoints::class.java)
    }
```

**Code for logging:**

```
   val response: Response<List<App>> = API.callBackend().getApplications()

   if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val appList = response.body()
                if (appList != null) {
                    Log.i("PARSED_", "size of list: "+appList.size)
                    for (app in appList) {
                        Log.i("PARSED_", "id: " + app.id + ", name: " + app.name)
                    }                        
                } 
             }
```

Yet, still my parsed instances **only have null values in every attribute**, why?

**Log:**

```
PARSED_  size of list: 2
PARSED_  id: null, name: null
PARSED_  id: null, name: null
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: One thing I notice is that `appVersion` is actually a `String` and not a `Number`. Try fixing all types to see if it helps. I'm actually also not familiar with using `Number` there, so I'm not sure if that's right either because I usually use `Int`. So fix the type of `appVersion` and if that doesn't help maybe also change `id` from `Number` to `Int`

Comment: @Ivo Tried it, also edited my app class in this question according to your suggestions, sadly same result.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out I had `minifyEnabled true` ini my `build.gradle` (Module version, not project version) file.

So I'll have to set it `false` or add a rule to `proguard-rules.pro` file to skip my App file (and also every other model class) for obfuscation.

Comment: I hate Proguard for exactly this reason: Whenever it breaks something, and it does so *a lot*, it's never clear that it's Proguard causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around, you can use `@Keep` for each of model class like this.

```
@Keep
class User {

private String name;
}
```